# How to access a variable from another module?

Tags: python

very noob to python, so if i have a file `A.py` for example with variable `a = 5` and a file `B.py`, I import `A` and try to print variable `a` and it gives me a `"module cannot find attribute"` error. how do i properly access a?

```
import A
print(A.a)
```

Comment: are both files in same directory? and did you import B in module A?

Answer (score 1):

If the files are in the same directory, you should be able to use:

```
import A
```

And then should be able to access the variables within.

Answer (score 0):

Both files should be in the same directory and try using functions so you can call them easily

Answer (score 0):

It depends on in which package the modules are lying. Just what you need to do is

```
from package_name/directory import module name 
access the variables, functions.
```

Just a eg:

I have a module 'a' in package stack, i imported using the from and import keyword and used this way.

```
from stack import a
print(a.a)
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all,Since you won't be using python's own module, you need like this: **from file_name import***

As for the files

this file inside B function:

```
from module_A import*

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        func_A = A()
        func_A.plus()
        print(func_A.a)
B()
```

and file module_A:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0
    def plus(self):
        self.a +=1
    def minus(self):
        self.a -=1
```

**What you need to be careful about here is to import the modules you have written with from and if you want to call a value inside the function make sure that item belongs to the class, like self.a not like a.**
by the way, be sure this two file be same directory